# how to fix IE text overlapping input padding

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

the texts are overlapping in input in all IE till IE9. I haven't test IE 10 yet. Looking for css hack or something like that

```
padding: 7px 35px 7px 5px !important;
```

the result in IE seems to be like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not option to solve with the same code.

You can append as `span` with image background.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think there is a trick for this, i suggest you apply the padding to a wrap element like this:

http://jsbin.com/udezuz/1/
this doesnt have the problem in IE where the right padding is ignored.